# Why are delegate properties given assign but commented weak in iOS7.1 SDK?

Tags: objective-c, ios7, automatic-ref-counting

Under ARC,
`assign` implies `__unsafe_unretained` ownership.
`weak` implies `__weak` ownership.

[image]

Why are delegate properties given `assign` but commented `weak` in iOS7.1 SDK?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

History. Prior to ARC, you used `assign` for "weak" (non-retaining) references. "Weak" just meant "I won't call retain on it" which translates into `assign`.

Before properties, we just knew that things called `delegate` didn't call `retain` by convention. Other non-retaining properties needed some kind of documentation.

There have been ongoing efforts to clean up the iOS SDK to conform to more modern conventions, but there are still places that use older approaches. I'm not exactly certain why they used `id` here, for instance, but it may be because of old habits around formal and informal protocols. Before ObjC 2, you couldn't have optional methods in a protocol, so you generally used informal protocols (i.e. you passed a bare `id`, and checked that it responded to what you needed). This style of commenting the protocol was often used in that case. (Not saying that's exactly the reason here; I believe UIAlertViewController post-dates ObjC 2. Just an example of things that take a long time to work their way out of the SDK.)

Comment: I'm confused about if there is the possibility that the delegating object will end up sending messages to the dead delegate.

Comment: Yes. It is the responsibility of the caller to make sure that the delegate out-lives the alert. This is often achieved by having the delegate own the alert, which is why `delegate` properties are usually assign/weak.

Comment: But `weak` also means "Set to nil automatically when the object died",so different from `assign`.

Comment: Correct. I am differentiating between "weak" and `weak`. We've used the term "weak" for decades in ObjC to mean what is now called `assign`. So if you see "weak" in header comments, it may not have the modern meaning of "zeroing weak reference."